# AWS ECR describe_image_scan_findings does not return findings

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ecr

strange issue i think. I am trying to automate gathering findings from AWS ECR image scans using Python Boto3 ECR client describe_image_scan_findings. I am able to get "findingSeverityCounts" in the response but the actual detailed "findings" are not returned with the response even though the documentation says they should be included.

So i try:

```
scan_report = ecr_client.describe_image_scan_findings(
            repositoryName=registry,
            imageId={
                'imageTag': most_recent_image
            },
            maxResults=1000
        )

        scan_findings = scan_report['imageScanFindings']
        pp.pprint(scan_report)
```

I get 'imageScanFindings': { 'findingSeverityCounts': {'HIGH': x}... etc in the response but  ['imageScanFindings']['findings'] are not returned with the finding details. Despite the boto3 docs specifying that as part of the response
[boto3 describe image scan findings](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecr.html#ECR.Client.describe_image_scan_findings)

What am i missing? Thx!!

Comment: Update - i have tested this in both AWS CLI and from python SDK with the same result. I then tried GO sdk and the response is Working. I'll check my python version and boto version and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, clearly it had something to do with the sdk version. I upgraded both python and boto and built a clean venv and now i get 'enhancedFindings' in the response which were not there before. Perhaps having enhanced findings enabled disables 'findings' and the old sdk version did not supply 'enhancedFindings'?

Just a guess, maybe this will help someone else